# Nginx server very slow

Tags: nginx, joomla

I have two joomla websites on a raspberry pi with nginx server.
One of them (the default one: www.sauvtag.com), is very very slow on the first request.

I don't know why. I'm a newbie on nginx.

Could you please help me?

here is my site-available configuration

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    listen   80 default_server; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
#   listen   [::]:80;  ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/sauvtag.com/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name sauvtag.com www.sautag.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.

expires 1d;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        deny all;
    }

    #cache navigateur
      location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|JPG|gif|ico|woff)$ {
                expires 7d;
        }
    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_cache nginxcache;
                fastcgi_cache_key $host$request_uri;
                fastcgi_cache_valid any 2h;
                fastcgi_cache_use_stale off;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
#   ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

here is also my nginx configuation file

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
client_max_body_size 3M;
     server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
        ##cache config fast cgi

        fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=nginxcache:10m inactive=2h max_size=1g;
    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

     gzip_vary on;
     gzip_proxied any;
     gzip_comp_level 6;
     gzip_buffers 16 8k;
     gzip_http_version 1.1;
     gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
         gzip_static on;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: What Joomla version are you running? Do you have an online copy i can look at? Maybe it's not on the server but on what you've added to Joomla?

Comment: what PI are you running this webserver on? Pi1 or a Pi2?

Comment: Have you checked the slow query log on the server?

Comment: Where can I check the query log?

Answer (score 0):

Hi every one first of all i'm running joomla 3.4 on a raspberry b+. I use a class 10 Sd card.
On joomla I use:
-communiquer builer
-jch-optimize (which minify HTML and css)

The request which is very very slow is the first get  request (for the HTML)

Maybe I should use a usb2 hard drive for the /www/ directory.

Note: I have another website on this raspberry (also running on joomla) which works perfecty.